# Git repo contains target directory

Tags: git

Our company just moved to Git.  It now appears we should have sorted out our **.gitignore** file before starting to check code in.  We now have several projects in the Git repo, including their Maven target directories (i.e. build directories).

I've run

```
git rm --cached <target dir path)
```

as well as adding

```
target/
```

to my .gitignore

However, whenever I pull, I'm still told there are unresolved merges with files in the target directory.  I suspect what needs to happen is that EVERYONE drawing code from the repo must do those same two steps in order for me to stop getting the unresolved merge messages.  Is that correct?  Or, is there something else that needs doing?

Comment: Is .gitignore part of the git repository, so that everyone has it?

Comment: Yes, everyone should be using the same one.

Comment: Did you commit and push after removing the unwanted files? What does git status say about your target directory?

Comment: Is `git rm --cache` actually valid?  [The documents](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm) say the flag is actually `--cached`.

Comment: @ColdHawaiian - Corrected the command in my question above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend:

```
git rm --cached -r target/
```

to be sure to remove from the index *all* files within target directory.

Then, as commented above, commit and push.
That modification will naturally propagate to other downstream repos, as thay will have to pull first (accepting your changes) before pushing.